# Skip has_many :through Model Creation on No Change

Tags: ruby, forms, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-models

This could be the wrong way to go about this entirely, and I'm very open to alternatives.

I've got the following models, where `Users` can have many `Positions`:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_positions
  has_many :positions, through: :user_positions

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_positions,
    reject_if: :all_blank
end

class UserPosition < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :position
end

class Position < ApplicationRecord
end
```

On my edit user form, I'd like to allow a `User`'s current position to be updated. I do that in the following way:

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :name %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>

  <%= f.fields_for :user_positions, @user.user_positions.order(created_at: :desc).first do |ff| %>
    <%= ff.hidden_field :user_id, value: @user.id %>
    <%= ff.collection_select :position_id, Position.all, :id, :label %>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.submit "Update User" %>
<% end %>
```

The issue I'm running into is that a new instance of `UserPosition` is being created every time I submit the form, even if the `Position` that's selected hasn't changed. This leads to a bunch of duplicate entries in the join table, when I really only care about "promotions" or "demotions" when the value of `position_id` has changed.

I don't want to add a custom validator to disallow the creation, because I still want the form to be able to submit with an unchanged position. An example of this is when I only want to change the `User`'s name.

Any advice on how to deal with this use case?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that you can actually use any method as a `Symbol` argument the to `accepts_nested_attributes_for` `reject_if` option.

I updated my `User` model as follows, and now the behavior is exactly what I want:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_positions
  has_many :positions, through: :user_positions

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_positions,
    reject_if: :same_as_previous_position

  def same_as_previous_position(attributes)
    if self.user_positions.empty?
      return false
    end

    Position.find(attributes[:position_id]) == self.user_positions.order(created_at: :desc).first.position
  end
end
```